# Can you transfer or "return" an undownloaded game on PSN? Accidentally purchased

Tags: ps4, psn

I own a PS4 and my roommate and I both have PSN accounts on it. I also recently got a new credit card. Last night I purchased 3 games and of course my card info wasn't pre-saved, so I entered it thinking it was my account. I downloaded one of them before realizing I was on the wrong account.

I understand that first one is probably a done deal and non-transferable but I didn't even start the downloads for the other two. Is there a way to "return" them so I can just buy them again on my account?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should be good with refunding for not-yet-downloaded stuff:

> If you started to download or stream the purchased content you are not eligible for a refund unless the content is faulty.

[Source](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/Requesting-a-Refund?language=en_US), it also advices to contact PlayStation Support to actually get refunds.